# Delays in Audio Playback Using Twilio API's Bi-directional Streaming

Tags: python, websocket, twilio, twilio-api

I am using the Twilio API for bi-directional streaming to transmit audio. However, I'm encountering a delay of about 4-5 seconds before the audio I send via WebSocket is actually played back on the phone.

I am looking for ways to reduce or eliminate this delay. I'm particularly interested in any WebSocket communication or Twilio API settings that might need tweaking. Also, I'd like to know if such a delay is typical or not.

Here's a snippet of my code for sending audio:

```py
await ws.send_text(data)
print("-------> Sent")
```

When I run this code, the audio starts playing on the phone 4-5 seconds after the "Sent" log appears.